# How to show validation errors in laravel api while having a form request file separate from controller

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have a form request file handling my validations separate from my controller. How do i return validation errors after an api call within the controller?

//my controller

```
/**
* Display a listing of the resource.
*
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function orders(GetOrdersRequest $request, OrderRepository $orderRepository)
{

    $order = $orderRepository->allOrders($request->paginate);

    return $this->sendSuccess('Orders retrieved successfully', $order);
}
```

Answer (score 16):

In the FormRequest class there is a function called `failedValidation`:

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    throw (new ValidationException($validator))
                ->errorBag($this->errorBag)
                ->redirectTo($this->getRedirectUrl());
}
```

It triggers when your validation fails. For API endpoints, this request is a bad response because it is a redirect and contains way too much information. To return a clean and
lightweight json respond, simply oerwrite the function `failedValidation` in your FormRequest for a matching response for your API. For example like this:

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    $errors = $validator->errors();

    $response = response()->json([
        'message' => 'Invalid data send',
        'details' => $errors->messages(),
    ], 422);

    throw new HttpResponseException($response);
}
```

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/56726819/2311074

Comment: this works for both API and web endpoints

Comment: This is what I am currently using, but as I am seeing if I have 8 controllers and each one with its respective PostNameRequest, the failedValidation code is going to be iterating on all of them, when perhaps the best thing in this case is to create an override of FormRequest that can call the method.
Do you think there is a possibility to do it only in one call? Something like that. $this->failedValidation(Validator $validator). I hope I have explained myself correctly.

Answer (score 6):

You will not be able to fetch the errors in that way since the FormRequest will throw an exception before the request reaches your controller in the event that there is a validation error. However, you can catch the error in the form request it self and modify the response there using the `failedValidation` method

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class OrderRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        //
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        //
    }

    public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        $errors = $validator->errors(); // Here is your array of errors
        throw new HttpResponseException($errors);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Laravel request class returns back **automatically** when validation fails. 
You should show your error messages in view(blade) file.
You can follow [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#working-with-error-messages).

For API's it returns automatically a JSON response including error messages.

Basically you can do it in blade file:

```
@if($errors->has('email'))
    <span class="error">{{ $errors->get('email') }}</span>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks but im not using the blade. I'm implementing apis which will be consumed by a frontend framework.

Comment: As i said, "For API's it returns automatically a JSON response including error messages".
You don't need do anything special. Laravel handle it.

Comment: Alright, thanks. But for some reasons, i do not get any error messages. I only get redirected to the laravel home screen - I'm using postman

Comment: "Accept: application/json"  add this header to postman as header.  Frontend frameworks use ajax therefore they don't need add this header. But when you try on postman you should add.

Comment: so you can select this post as answer?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `accept: application/json` into your headers in postman or whatever you are using for API testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not possible, but you can use the prepareForValidation()  method within you FormRequest and manipulate data before validate.

Comment: it's possible. I had to add the Accept: application/json header in my postman

Answer (score 0):

Even when using form request, Laravel handles validation for you automatically without you doing anything. On failed validation, an `errors` will be returned that you can access in your request response. `response.data.errors` (depending on the library you use for requests, of course) will contain the errors. For example:

```
errors: {
    name: ["The name must be at least 2 characters"]
}
```

This is just a dummy example.
Do a quick test by forcing the request to fail and console log the response to see how it will show.